# How to tell if a verb is followed by preposition or adverb particle?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I learn from *Oxford English Grammar Course:Advanced* by Swan that verbs with adverb particles are often called Phrasal Verbs.

An example to illustrate my confusion, I'm doing the exercise about determining whether the given sentence is using preposition or adverb particle. This is one of the sentences:

> I **looked up** the street to see if Andy was coming.

The answer key told me it's a preposition, but I found the phrase **look up** listed as a phrasal verb in OALD which means to *raise your eyes when you are looking down at something*. I also ever read somewhere that *phrasal verbs* are just *verbs + prepositions*. Does that mean each author might have different view? I'm pretty sure I've read that, but I can't tell where, I don't remember.

Related to the title, so how do you tell precisely if the small word that comes after a verb is preposition or adverb particle? For example, an English learner might not be able to tell which one is *verb + preposition* and *verb + adverb particle*:

> He **got off** the bus.[1]
>
> I **switch off** the lamp.[2]

I took those examples from the book I've mentioned above. The book says [1] is *verb + preposition* and [2] is *verb + adverb particle*. I'm hopeless if I have to remember one-by-one and start to memorize which is preposition and which is adverb particle.

Comment: _Look up_ can mean _raise your eyes_ (intransitive) or _search for something in a reference source_ (transitive). However, I would parse your sentence as "I looked _up the street_..." , where _up the street_ means 'towards a point some distance along the street'.

Comment: The book is right, though "off" is also a preposition, not an adverb. In [2], "off" qualifies as a particle because it can occur between the verb and its direct object, as well as after the object:  _I switch off the lamp_ ~ _I switch the lamp off_. But In [1] "off" does not qualify as a particle because it cannot occur after the object: We can't say *"He got the bus off".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general way to tell: sometimes such sentences are genuinely ambiguous, even to native speakers.

Answer (score 2):

> [1] *He got off the bus*.
>
> [2] *I switch off the lamp*.

Preliminary point: particles are the only complements which can freely come between the verb and its direct object. They are mainly prepositions - intransitive ones, of course, since they are one-word phrases - though the class of particles also contains some adjectives and verbs.

The book is right here, though "off" is a preposition in both examples. In [2], "off" qualifies as a particle because it can occur between the verb and its direct object, as well as after the object: *I switch off the lamp* ~ *I switch the lamp off.*

But In [1] "off" does not qualify as a particle because it cannot occur after the object: We can't say **He got the bus off*.

> [3] *I looked up the street to see if Andy was coming.*

In [3], "up" is a preposition. But it's not a particle since we can't say *We looked the street up*, without a change of meaning.